# How to change javascript:__doPostBack Url to full Url

Tags: asp.net, seo

I'm an SEO by profession and I have recently developed a database driven ASP.NET site. I have a problem with my website's internal linking. My links are shown as `doPostBack`, but I want them to display the actual URL so that search engines can crawl them.

Current: This is link pattern in my sidebar. All links are in this format

```
<ul>
<li><a id="linkHome" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$linkHome& #39;,&#39;&#39">Home</a></li>
```

This is just one link from the sidebar. All links are in this format. I want them to be like

```
<li><a id="linkHome" href="http://www.example.com">Home</a></li>
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: you need to offer how your navigation works.do you use one .aspx-page or do you have multiple .aspx-pages.do you use standard asp.net navigation components

Comment: SLaks we have multiple aspx.net pages. Basically I just sent him all of my requirements with SEO perspective. IS there any way for me to show you my site?

Comment: Yes we are using standard navigation side bar that shows on all the pages.

Answer (score 2):

Tell your developer to use normal href links for those if they're links instead of `asp:LinkButton` which is what he's using I think. Alternatively move to MVC and use the MVC router. He's using server side controls for what (you're telling me) can be client side links (standard anchor tags) The `asp:LinkButton` causes server side processing just to handle a link which is silly if the pages can be reached directly with no need to make a server request.

edit:

For a little more detail, here's what your developer is probably doing, either:

```
<asp:LinkButon runat="server" id="linkHome" OnClick="linkHome_OnClick" Text="Home" />
```

or maybe

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="linkHome" NavigateUrl="example.com" Text="Home" />
```

what he should do is simply:

```
<a href="example.com">Home</a>
```

Comment: SLaks could you please guide me so that i can show a way out to my developer. This issue is very imp for me.

Comment: Thank u so much. That's really helpful. Now I can show him this thread. The guy is very dedicated but still he needs to learn alot of things. Thanks